# File opening dialog box with Eclipse Visual Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-editor

Is there an open file dialog box in Eclipse's Visual Editor? Like the windows or linux Open File dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You open an existing file with the Visual Editor.  Check the Right-click -> "Open With..." dialogue.

Comment: No, perhaprs I didn't explain it right.
I am building a GUI, and I need the user to select a file from the file system. In VB for example there is some sort of file dialog that allows the user to select a file. I need something like that in Java (Visual Editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a Swing GUI then you can use a [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) Dialog. I am not sure that there is a visual widget for this in the VE but you do have an option to add any bean using the **Choose Bean** option. [This article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-VE-Custom-Widget/customwidget.html) has a bit about using Choose Bean. However, I think it would be far simpler to do the File Chooser by code in response to an event such as a button click.